# How to propagate sleuth traceid,spanid to aws lambda function

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, trace, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I want to trace a request which comes to my webservice and sends an sns notification which will trigger a aws lambda function. Any way to create a new span with same trace id in my lambda function.

Comment: I'm absolutely no expert on AWS Lambda but if you ensure that the notification contains proper headers then your Lambda function could reuse it on its side. I'd need to see the code and you'd need to guide me on how all of this stuff works.

Comment: I can send required data to the lambda function. How do I configure sleuth on lambda to read the data and correlate the trace.

Comment: Let's move this discussion to  https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Do you have any answer?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use such an abstraction like Spring Cloud Function (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function). You can read more about this here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR1/single/spring-cloud.html#_aws_lambda